# Regex: any string in a pattern that starts with a specific character, followed by any character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to work out the right regular expression that given a pattern like this:

```
@ abDC email@something.com 123 %&#
@ deFG @@anything 123 = 56
@@ HIjk @@lolol 123 = 78
```

Results in the following matches:

```
match 1:
@ abDC email@something.com 123 %&#

match 2:
@ deFG @@anything 123 = 56
@@ HIjk @@lolol 123 = 56
```

In words: any string that starts with a single "@" followed by any character, including line breaks, white spaces and occurrences of "@" itself.

I've tried with `@{1}.+`, but that results in three separate matches instead of the expected two. See on [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40%7B1%7D.%2B&i=%40%20abDC%20email%40something.com%20123%20%25%26%23%0D%0A%40%20deFG%20%40%40anything%20123%20%3C%3E%3D%2056%0D%0A%40%40%20HIjk%20%40%40lolol%20123%20%3C%3E%3D%2078).

Comment: `{1}` is redundant as that's default behaviour

Comment: What about [`^(@.+)\n*([\s\S]*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%40.%2b%29%5cn*%28%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%29&i=%40+abDC+email%40something.com+123+%25%26%23%0d%0a%40+deFG+%40%40anything+123+%3c%3e%3d+56%0d%0a%40%40+HIjk+%40%40lolol+123+%3c%3e%3d+78)?

Comment: `$@.*` try it maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may match lines that start with a single `@` and may optionally contain lines below starting with double `@`:

```
(?m)^@(?!@)[^\r\n]*(?:\r?\n@@[^\r\n]*)*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%40%28%3F!%40%29%5B%5E%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%40%40%5B%5E%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%29*&i=%40%20abDC%20email%40something.com%20123%20%25%26%23%0D%0A%40%20deFG%20%40%40anything%20123%20%3C%3E%3D%2056%0D%0A%40%40%20HIjk%20%40%40lolol%20123%20%3C%3E%3D%2078)

**Details**

- `(?m)` - multiline modifier
- `^` - start of a line
- `@`  - a `@` char
- `(?!@)` - not followed with `@`
- `[^\r\n]*` - the rest of the line before `\r\n` or `\n`
- `(?:\r?\n@@[^\r\n]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line break
  - `@@` - a `@@` substring
  - `[^\r\n]*` - the rest of the line.

Note that `[^\r\n]*` is used rather than `.*` just because in .NET regex, `.` matches CR. If that is not important, you may use

```
(?m)^@(?!@).*(?:\n@@.*)*
```